# solving custom equations using pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dateframe like below.

```
     b0         b1         b2         b3            b4         b5 
b0  1.0     -0.005495     NaN       0.285714       NaN         NaN 
b1  -182.0  1.000000    2.500000    6.666667    -3.937500   5.190476]
b2  NaN     0.400000    1.000000    -0.408377   0.178571    10.000000
b3  3.5     0.150000    -2.448718   1.000000      NaN       3.407407
b4  NaN     -0.253968   5.600000       NaN      1.000000    -0.196319
```

- lets say b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5 are also like variables.
- b0 row, b0 column represent b0/b0.
- b0 row, b1 column represent b0/b1.
- and so on.
- when i assign a value to b0 as 10.
- from equation b0/b1 = -0.005495, i can get b1 as -181.98.
- so now we have equations like these and I want to get the solutions for b1,b2,b3,b4,b5 using code.
- In my actual problem there are 2000 variables and more than 4000 ratios, clearly have more equations than variables.
- Need to pick a set of equations to solve them and subsequently reduce the error for other ratios iteratively.
- And some ratios don't exist which are represented by nan

Can i know how should these be solved

Comment: Incidentally, something seems strange about your matrix. The i-j entry should be 1 divided by the j-i entry, but some of your entries are 0, for which this is impossible. You might consider replaces those with nan.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I changed them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If `b0 = 10`, then

```
b0 * df['b0']
```

will give you a series whose index is the different bs, and the value is the corresponding values. Specifically, you will get that the first value is 10 (corresponding to b0), and the second value is -2141.09 (corresponding to b1).

Comment: i actually have 2000*2000 matrix, say for b0/b2, it is nan, so i can't get the b2 value from first row so can i know what i should do to get these variable values.

Comment: If you have a nan entry, I’m afraid there are only two possibilities: your matrix is inconsistent (some parts contradict others), or, if not, it’s truly impossible to find the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the ratio between any two variables, just multiply the entire data frame by whatever value you're looking for, and then extract the relevant cell. For example:

`(df * 10).loc["b1", "b0"]`